# replace deprecated sizeWithFont with sizeWithAttributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, sizewithfont

How can I produce following code using sizeWithAttributes method:

```
CGFloat labelWidth = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font].width;
```

I need to have label width!

Comment: What iOS version you are supporting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this

```
CGSize size = [string sizeWithAttributes:
                       @{NSFontAttributeName:
                         [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];
```

Comment: you are getting CGSize in CGFloat, which is wrong

Comment: ohhh sorry i update my anser..:)

Comment: What is the source of your 17.0f? The question does not include a particular font size.

Comment: Why is 17.0f hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat labelWidth = [label.text sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary 
                      dictionaryWithObject:label.font forKey:NSFontAttributeName]].width;
```